# Salesforce Button -Unexpected Number

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I tried adding a custom button on the page and I received the error saying "Unexpected Number". Here is the code.

> The OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Balance__c is a formula field of type currency. I did try adding $ before 0.00 but it still threw the same error

```
else if ({!OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Is_Refund__c
} && {!OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Balance__c
    } = 0.00) {
        alert('Refund processed. DO you wish to continue');
    } else if ({!OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Is_Refund__c
        }) {
            //alert('in refund loop'); 
            rec.OrderApi__Process_Refund__c = true;
            sforce.connection.update([rec]);
        }location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Though this comment is not related to this question but it is observed that you are not selecting answers as accepted to your questions though your purpose got resolved and members are devoting their time and effort to solve your issue. Accepting answers will help to identity the best answers and person got reputation helping your issues, that's the way community works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currency formula or field already returns currency indicator along with the value.

So, even amount is `0.00`, it will return `$0.00`;

Better, trim off the $ and verify the amount as below.

```
var amountStr = '{!OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Balance__c}';
var actualValue = amountStr.substr(1, amountStr.length-1);

if(actualValue == 0.00)
{
     alert('Final amount is zero');
}
else
{
    alert('Final amount is not zero');
}
```

So, final code will look like this:

```
var amountStr = '{!OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Balance__c}';
var actualValue = amountStr.substr(1, amountStr.length-1);

else if('{!OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Is_Refund__c}'&& actualValue ==0.00)
{ 
   alert('Refund processed. DO you wish to continue'); 
}else if('{!OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Is_Refund__c}') { 
   //alert('in refund loop'); 
rec.OrderApi__Process_Refund__c = true; 
    sforce.connection.update([rec]); 
} 
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: I did try that and I get the following error : " Invalid left hand side in assignment"

Comment: use actualValue ==0.00 in if condition

Comment: This code assumes the user is configured for the United States locale and may break for other locales.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the formula syntax as an alternative:

```
else if( {!AND( OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Is_Refund__c,
           OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Balance__c = 0) } ) {
```

Using this syntax allows you to get compiler errors instead of having to troubleshoot JavaScript. This means you no longer have to trim off the $ or worry about locale errors, and also supports multicurrency if you decide to use it in the future.

Comment: if I omit the first condition and verify this: `if('{!OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Balance__c}' = 0)` , it will give `invalid left side assignment` error, also if I use, `if('{!OrderApi__Receipt__c.OrderApi__Balance__c}' == 0) `, it will return false always, as it returns $0.00 for currency type formula field

Comment: for that sake of testing I have created a formula field in Opportunity object referring Amount of the Opportunity

Comment: @SantanuBoral You mis-read the answer: the entire thing is unquoted and within the merge field. Doing this eliminates any need to parse anything in JavaScript whatsoever, as JavaScript will only see `else if( true )` or `else if( false )`.

Comment: Can you please run this code at your DE and let me know your findings: alert('{!Opportunity.Final_Amount__c}'); 
if('{!Opportunity.Final_Amount__c}' == 0) 
{ 
 alert('Final amount is zero'); 
} 
else 
{ 
 alert('Final amount is not zero'); 
}

Comment: where Final_Amount__c is currency formula related to Amount field

Comment: @SantanuBoral You're still missing my point. You try *this* code in your DE: `if({!Opportunity.Final_Amount__c=0}) { alert('Final Amount is zero'); } else { alert('Final Amount is not zero'); }`. Make sure you copy and paste exactly.